# Strategies for beating Pumpking as a Mage?

Tags: terraria

I'm playing through Terraria using nothing but magic weapons, and I'm having a really difficult time with the end-game events (I have defeated all of the single bosses, with the exception of Duke Fishron). Virtually all of the ideal mage builds I see on the internet involve the [Bat Scepter](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bat_Scepter), which is dropped by the [Pumpking](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pumpking). But, no matter what weapon combinations I try, I just can't seem to beat the Pumpking using magic weapons.

Are there any particular strategies for taking him down as a mage? I've built an arena with traps, I'm using the [Spectre armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Specter_Armor) (with hood), and I'm using a Nimbus Rod, Rainbow gun, and Heat Ray. I can wade through the first few waves in the Pumpkin Moon event (up to wave 9 or so, albeit dying many times), but I just can't bring down the Pumpking.

Comment: What accessories are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using Lightning Boots, wings (I forget which type), Sorcerer's Emblem, Celestial Stone, and Magic Cuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spectre Hood armor set has pretty significant damage reduction (40%). I found using the Hallowed armor for boss fights (or wave events) more effective.
I use a long-ish (about a screen length) area with a pit in the middle for traps. With this set-up, potions typically suffice for me.

I think your accessories look good, I usually use a similar setup.  Depending on how much you're running, you may want to switch out the boots.  I recommend something like [Charm of Myths](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Charm_of_Myths) to reduce pot cooldown.

For weapons, I think the Heat Ray is good for the regular monsters, but you want something with high single-target damage for bosses.  I've used the [Leaf Blower](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Leaf_Blower) fairly successfully against the Mourning Wood and Pumpking.

With this set-up, I can get 1-2 Pumpking kills a night.  Not much, but it's a start. Things to improve would be reforging accessories for better modifiers, and making a better arena that kills the regular monsters for you, allowing you to focus on the bosses.

Answer (score 0):

Try a war of attrition: use a Mana Flower, stock up a LOT of potions, build several very long levels of platforms and fight the Pumpking by dodging and slowly wearing it down with homing weapons like the Spectre Staff. Also try buff potions like the Magic Power potion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming to fight Pumpking alone and not aiming for the rest of the Pumpkin Moon event there is actually an easy tactic regardless of weapon choice, the main requirement is a good pair of wings(works with rocket boots but much harder).

Build a few layers of mine cart tracks in the air(at least 50 tiles above ground where monsters can spawn) - not platform as monsters can still spawn of those. It does not have to be very wide, 100 tiles is more than enough. If you are short of tracks you can instead build loose segments floating around.

During the fight(once pumpking spawns), fly near tracks and hook onto one segment then fly in circle(as large a circle as you can draw without dropping back to the ground) and use hook on the mine cart tracks to stay in air. The pumpking's movement will almost never hit you if you do it properly. The rest is just up to how much you can hit them while performing those aerial acrobatics.

Alternatively if you already have the cosmic car keys for the flying saucer mount you can just fly in circles in the air making it much easier to focus on attacking.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it easy,try sticking to beating the Moon Lord first to get strong weapons.Then start fighting the Pumpking.

Comment: Seeing as the Moon Lord is even harder than the Pumpking/Pumpkin Moon event, this isn't really a good idea.